# How to add dynamic a javascript variable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I add variable length list in a view with jquery.

```
 $("#addItemday").click(function() {
  $.get("/Course/AddDayNewRow", function(data) {
  $("#DayEditorRows").append(data);
  }).fail(function(xhr, err) {
   alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
   });
  });
```

for every partialview, set a index value.for example

```
<input name="Days.index" autocomplete="off" value="96633b1d-9c0c-4760-9ca8-474ac28bd52a" type="hidden">
```

I want to add a script for every partialview.

```
var objCal1 = new AMIB.persianCalendar("objCal1", "dateid");
```

After append PartialView, i want to get last item added.

```
 $("input[id*='Date']").last(function () {
  var ??? = new AMIB.persianCalendar(???, $(this).attr('id'));});
```

How do i get last item addes, and set name for this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two questions, two answer:

1) To get the id of the last item that you added:

```
 var last_id = $("input").last().attr("id");
```

Remember that you have to wait for your AJAX call to return before firing that, so add it within your AJAX function.

2) Name the variable whatever you like.

Here's an example of the total code:

```
$("#addItemday").click(function() {
       $.get("/Course/AddDayNewRow", function(data) {
           $("#DayEditorRows").append(data);
           var last_id = $("input").last().attr("id");
           var amib_var = new AMIB.persianCalendar(last_id);
           // DO SOMETHING WITH THE AMIB_VAR
       }).fail(function(xhr, err) {
           alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
           alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
   });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, I get id, but i want to add variable for every partial with diferent name, add should add this variable to body , for example add `<script> var objCal1 = new AMIB.persianCalendar("objCal1", "dateid"); </script>` for every partial in body.

Comment: Ok. I don't know the context of what you're doing here, which makes it difficult. If you have a Fiddle with the whole thing, that'd be great. However, creating a variable with the name of a returned object is almost certainly not necessary. If you need to execute something on every "input" field, just use $("input").each(function(){//do something}) to iterate - use your DOM instead of duplicating the data into variables. But if you really need to duplicate the data, put it into an object. See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x01c05ab/